# Creating clusters in a sortable bar chart in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I making a bar chart in D3, in total there are 18 bars to the series and I'm trying to show how the all of the bars cluster into ranges of Low, Med, and High (six bars in each range). I'd like there to be visual gaps between these each of these clusters (so they are clearly distinct) - the issue is that the bars can be resorted based on other data not shown in the chart (think demographic data to see how the bars cluster in different ways).

[Here's what it looks like now](http://jsfiddle.net/gaK9k/)

and here's my code for making and sorting the bars

```
        svg.selectAll("rect.bars")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bars")
            .attr("x", 0 + padding)
            .attr("y", function(d, i){
                return yScale(i);
            })
            .attr("width", function(d) {
                return xScale(d.values[0]);
            })
            .attr("height", yScale.rangeBand())


        d3.select("#yield")
            .on("click", function(){
                svg.selectAll("rect.bars")
                    .sort(function(a, b){
                        return d3.ascending(a.values[0], b.values[0])
                    })
                    .transition()
                    .delay(function(d, i){
                        return i *50;
                    })
                    .duration(1000)
                    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
                        return yScale(i)
                    });
            });

        d3.select("#richPatch")
            .on("click", function(){
                svg.selectAll("rect.bars")
                    .sort(function(a, b){
                        return d3.ascending(a.values[1], b.values[1])
                    })
                    .transition()
                    .delay(function(d, i){
                        return i *50;
                    })
                    .duration(1000)
                    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
                        return yScale(i)
                    });

            });

        d3.select("#patchMoves")
            .on("click", function(){
                svg.selectAll("rect.bars")
                    .sort(function(a, b){
                        return d3.ascending(a.values[2], b.values[2])
                    })
                    .transition()
                    .delay(function(d, i){
                        return i *50;
                    })
                    .duration(1000)
                    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
                        return yScale(i)
                    });

            });
```

Ultimately I'm trying to make it look something like this (but horizontally laid out)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you create a `d3.scale.ordinal` using [ordinal.rangeBands](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#wiki-ordinal_rangeBands) you'll end up with a scale that is broken up into discrete bands based on the number of values in your domain (3 in your case). Scaling the values will return the location of the beginning of the relevant band.

Ordinal scales configured with `rangeBands` have a nice convenience function called [ordinal.rangeBand](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#wiki-ordinal_rangeBand) that will return the extent of the bands.  So you can start by scaling your bar position to the beginning of the band and this do a little bit of math based on the extent of the band with the number of bars and the width of each bar to simply spread out the bars evenly across the band.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but I'm not sure this will work because all the bars are technically on the same graph (they aren't 3 different graphs), so distributing them evenly will only do it across the whole graph (and not the individual rangeBands). Or is there some way to spread say 1st-child to nth-child(6) across one band and nth-child(7) to nth-child(12) across another.

Comment: The bars are grouped by X value (Low, Middle, High).  So the 6 bars that are Low will all have the same scaled X value at the beginning of the Low band (all identical position so bars overlapping).  From there you can spread out the overlapping bars across the Low rangeBand.  Same thing for the other bands.